# Cannot POST /api/hotels - 404 not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to create a new hotel by using the below API call.

[Here you can see the relevant POST request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hSJ2P.png)

I can see that the application is running:

*Connected to backend.
mongoDB connected!
Connected to mongoDB.
...

However couldn't access the api/hotels endpoint. **Cannot GET /api/hotels**

Any ideas where I am making a mistake here?

**routes/hotels.js**

```
import express from "express";
import Hotel from "../models/Hotel.js";
import {
    createHotel,
    deleteHotel,
    getHotel,
    getHotels,
    updateHotel,
  } from "../controllers/hotel.js";

const router = express.Router();

//CREATE
router.post("/", createHotel);
//UPDATE
router.put("/:id", updateHotel);
///DELETE
router.delete("/:id", deleteHotel);
//GET
router.get("/:id", getHotel);
//GET ALL
router.get("/", getHotels);

export default router;
```

**controllers/hotel.js**

```
import Hotel from "../models/Hotel.js"
export const createHotel = async (req,res,next)=>{
    const newHotel = new Hotel(req.body);

    try{
        const savedHotel = await newHotel.save();
        res.status(200).json(savedHotel);
    }   catch (err) {
        next(err);
    }
};
export const updateHotel = async (req,res,next) => {
    try {
      const updatedHotel = await Hotel.findByIdAndUpdate(
        req.params.id,
        { $set: req.body },
        { new: true }
      );
      res.status(200).json(updatedHotel);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
};
export const deleteHotel = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      await Hotel.findByIdAndDelete(req.params.id);
      res.status(200).json("Hotel has been deleted.");
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
};
export const getHotel = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const hotel = await Hotel.findById(req.params.id);
      res.status(200).json(hotel);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
};
export const getHotels = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
      const hotels = await Hotel.find();
      res.status(200).json(hotels);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
    }
};
```

**index.js**

```
// import express from "express";
// import dotenv from "dotenv";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import express from "express";
import authRoute from "./routes/auth.js";
import usersRoute from "./routes/users.js";
import hotelsRoute from "./routes/hotels.js";
import roomsRoute from "./routes/rooms.js";

const app = express();
// dotenv.config()

const connect = async ()=>{
    try {
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb+srv://******@******.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority');
        // Check how we can use .env file
        console.log("Connected to mongoDB.")
    }   catch (error) {
        throw error 
    }  
};


mongoose.connection.on("disconnected", ()=>{
    console.log("mongoDB disconnected!")
})
mongoose.connection.on("connected", ()=>{
    console.log("mongoDB connected!")
})

// middlewares

app.use(express.json())

app.use("api/auth", authRoute);
app.use("api/users", usersRoute);
app.use("api/hotels", hotelsRoute);
app.use("api/rooms", roomsRoute);

app.use((err, req,res,next)=>{
 return res.status(500).jsom("Hello error from handler!")
})

app.listen(8800, ()=>{
    connect()
    console.log("Connected to backend.")
    app.get('/', (_, res) => res.send({message: 'Hello from Express'}))
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use just `router.post("/"` instead of `router.post("/api/hotels"`, because now full path for your endpoint is `/api/hotels/api/hotels`

Comment: I've received the same error.

Comment: @amerigo Can you access updating endpoint (PUT)?

Comment: no it is the same response

Comment: @amerigo Can you access root endpoint (GET "/") and receive response `{message: 'Hello from Express'}`?

Comment: yes, I can get a response

Comment: Hello, I've changed the code and started to use controllers. You can see the edited comment. Would it be possible if you have a look at the final version and share your opinion why I still don't get any response of /api/hotels or /api/auth?

Answer (score 0):

### Hotel Model

```
const newHotel = new Hotel(req, body)
```

And within the definition of `Hotel`. I am assuming that Hotel looks something like this for the sake of the example:

```
const hotelSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ hotelName: 'string', rooms: 'number' });
export const Hotel = mongoose.model('Hotel', hotelSchema);
```

When you call an instance of the new Schema it should be done this way:

```
const newHotel = new Hotel({rooms: 4, hotelName: "Shuraton"})
```

and not:

```
const newHotel = new Hotel(req, body)
```

Anyway, it would be a good practice to validate the `request.body`, and sanitize the input before. You can do that with `Joi` `express-validtor` or `ajv`.

### Correct endpoint

- Your endpoint currently is `/api/hotels/api/hotels`. Fix it by removing `api/hotels` from `hotels.js`

```
router.post("/", async (req,res)=>{
    const newHotel = new Hotel(req, body)

    try{
        const savedHotel = await newHotel.save()
        res.status(200).json(savedHotel)
    }catch(err){
        res.status(500).json(err)
    }
})
```

Let me know if that helped.
Edit: added fix for endpoint

Comment: Thank you for your answer Jonatan. However, I am not familiar with request.body validation. I guess I need to do some research and try again :)

Comment: request.body is a 'channel' where you can get content from the user. Sometimes, that content might be malicious. To avoid that, you 'validate' / 'sanitize' it, to prevent bad actors to perform unwanted operations. They are super easy to set.

Comment: I think that the solution to your problem is actually both solutions, the one saying about `router.post` and this one about the Hotel Model.

Comment: I've tried this approach to see if it gets any return but couldn't see the console log. 

  `'router.get("/", async (req, res, next) => {

    console.log("hi im a hotel route")
    next()
    try{
        const hotels = await Hotel.find();
        res.status(200).json(hotels);
    }   catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json(err);
    }
    }); '`

Comment: Is the server running? Are you using nodemon for development? does any other route return something?

Comment: The server is running but I can't access the /api/hotels endpoint. I don't use nodemon. Other routes are not working as well. Only http://localhost:8800/ returns reponse

Comment: Place a `router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Hello from hotels`) inside your hotels.js. Restart your server. Then try to make a request to `localhost:8800/api/hotels/api/hotels`). Do you get the hello message?

Comment: This is the latest situation. Still couldn't reach out to  localhost:8800/api/hotels/api/hotels and localhost:8800/api/hotels endpoints. I don't see the hello message. This is the output: 

Connected to backend.
mongoDB connected!
Connected to mongoDB.


`import express from "express";
import Hotel from "../models/Hotel.js";
const router = express.Router();
router.get('/', (req, res) => res.send("Hello from hotels"));
`

Comment: I fixed the code,I will publish a new answer.

Answer (score 0):

### File with all fixes implemented:

### hotels.js

Remove all `/api/hotel` and fix the line of `new Hotel(req.body)`:

```
import express from "express";
import Hotel from "../models/Hotel.js";

const router = express.Router();

//CREATE
router.get("/", (req, res) => {
  return res.json("Hello from hotels");
});

//CREATE
router.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  const newHotel = new Hotel(req.body);
  try {
    const savedHotel = await newHotel.save();
    res.status(200).json(savedHotel);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

//UPDATE
router.put("/:id", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const updatedHotel = await Hotel.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {
      $set: req.body,
    });
    res.status(200).json(updatedHotel);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
//DELETE

//GET

//GET ALL
export default router;
```

Comment: I appreaciate for your effort Jonatan. Still, I don't get any response "Cannot GET /api/hotels"

Comment: Hi Jonatan, I've changed the code and started to use controllers. You can see the edited comment. Would it be possible if you have a look at the final version and share your opinion why I still don't get any response of /api/hotels or /api/auth?

Comment: Okay, found the solution. I need to use "/api/auth" instead of "api/auth" inside of the app.use function. I forgot to use slash before api/auth. Thank you for your all help Jonatan. 

basically it looks like: app.use("/api/auth", authRoute);